# View Camera: decoupling view rotation from camera

Tags: animation, camera, grease-pencil, 2d

I'm trying out Grease Pencil for 2D animation. When I start drawing, I naturally use the View Camera (shortcut: NumPad 0), whose rectangular outline delineates the 2D canvas.

But when looking through the View Camera, the `view3d.rotate_canvas` function rotates not only the view but also the camera itself, modifying the canvas, which I don't want.

I tried locking the camera's Z rotation, which just disables canvas rotation completely.

The behaviour is the same in Grease Pencil's Draw Mode and in other modes.

The only workaround I've found so far is to create a rectangle in Draw Mode to (more or less) match the canvas outline.

Is there a way to lock the camera's orientation when rotating the view / canvas?

Edit: I've added screenshots to show the initial state of the camera, and below, what the camera does when rotating the canvas.

[image: Top: default orientation of the camera. Bottom: when the canvas is rotated.]

Comment: Hello, could you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: Done, they should make things clearer.

Comment: It looks like you're rotating the camera, not the canvas. Grease Pencil doesn't really have a canvas, per se; it's just a white 3d space with the brushstrokes and the camera, which gives the illusion of it being 2d.

Comment: Yes, I use the term "canvas" informally here, but the concept clearly exists in Blender, as evidenced by the name of the keyboard shortcut: "rotate_canvas".